# Can a service provider proof it is running a particular open source product?

Tags: open-source, source-code, validation

Part of our project includes an open source GO server that we have open sourced for transparency. How can we prove that we havent made any alterations to the code before we deployed it?

Comment: Who is asking for the proof?

Comment: Include a digital signature with your code and your binary, using some public utility like PGP.  Whoever wants to can verify the digital signature against their own binary.

Comment: Running code and deploying code are different things. Please make clear which you really mean.

Comment: Its not the binary we are concerned with, but actually being able to prove that what we have running is exactly what the code is providing. We have considered an outside auditor, but i was hoping for a technical mechanism.

Comment: @r2DoesInc I don't think any technical mechanism is possible. If you think about it, even if you have a machine with all kinds of boot verification, software signing, secure boot, and some sort of mechanism that allows outside parties to peer into the registers, RAM and all other internal workings, how can you prove that machine is the only that's actually doing the processing, and isn't just a honey pot?

Comment: @r2DoesInc Even if your system incorporated some element of "you know it's real because you can see your request come into RAM and be handled over here", nothing is stopping you from hiding a proxy in front of this "visible" server, which is taking the data and doing nefarious things (e.g. leaking customer info)

Comment: That was all pretty much my thinking, but I was hoping there may have been something that I hadnt considered. Thank you all.

Comment: The only way that I know of to do what you're describing is to let users of your open source project compile from source and deploy the executable themselves.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: Then you still run into the problem described by Ken Thompson in his ACM Turing Award Lecture *Reflections on Trusting Trust*.

Comment: You forgot to explain the most important: what kind of proof do you want ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No that is impossible. Even if you included a service method that has some challenge/response mechanism, the service provider could run a proxy and pass on the request. And any mechanism could be reproduced easily because it is all open.

Even knowing they are running the same sever would not guarantee it would behave as expected. Results could be input dependent and the input could be local/configurable, impossible for you to verify.

I understand, transparency is all the rage now and you basically want to proof you are not Facebook, right? I would dedicate a page on my website to this and provide the warm feeling from there. You will need a good text writer though.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I know you could solve is by find a [trusted third party](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_third_party), hand your code over to them and let them compile and run it (maybe on a neutral cloud platform). If you want to provide / host the server on your own, you will probably have to let the trusted third party audit your internal processes.

Comment: That was my thought for having an outside auditor come and validate our statements.